# Why does Laravel login attempt redirects back to the login page?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Laravel redirect me back to the login page after each attempt to login. How do i fix this issue?

I've tried changing the session from 'file' to 'database' and clearing all the cache(both in the browser and in laravel, yet it's still redirects back to the login page)

*Here is the web route:*

```
 // Login
 Route::post("/profile/dashboard","LoginController@login")->name('login');
```

*Here is my controller:*

```
    public function login(Request $req)
    {
        // validate form
       $req->validate([
            "email" => "required|email|max:255",
            "password" => "required|max:16",
        ]);

        $user = ["email" => $req->email, "password" => $req->password];

        // Attempt to login
        if (!Auth::attempt($user)) {

            return back();

        }
        // Redirects to dashboard
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
```

*Sorry for the poor formatting. Here is my view:*

```
   <form action="{{ url("/profile/dashboard") }}" 
        method="post" class="user">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control 
          form-control-user" aria-describedby="emailHelp"   placeholder="Enter Email Address...">
                          <label class="error" for="email">
                            @include("pages.errors.email")
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control form-control-user" placeholder="Password">
                          <label class="error" for="password">
                            <label class="error" for="password">
                              @include("pages.errors.password")
                            </label>
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox small">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck">
                            <label class="custom-control-label form-check-label" for="customCheck">Remember Me</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-user btn-block text-uppercase">Login</button>
                        <hr>
    <a href="index.html" class="btn  btn-danger btn-google 
     btn-user btn-  block text-uppercase">
                          <i class="fab fa-google"></i> Login with Google
                        </a>
  </form>
```

*I dont't if this will help but here is my session set to database:*

```
   'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),
```

No Error was generate. It redirects back to the login page without any given error.

Comment: Auth::attempt($user) return you back. That means record not exist in db. Make sure user email and password are correct

Comment: That's not the reason for the redirection, because tested it by die-and-dumping the some data and it still redirect me back, plus the email and the password are correct. Everything was working fine, then all of sudden it stopped logging in and instead redirected me back

Comment: Share code of dashboard.

Comment: @RomeoAgbor Is it possible you added a conflicting route? Check `php artisan route:list`.

Comment: @ceejayoz I tried it and it worked! I had three route with the same URl. I wonder why I din't think of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

> So, what if the incoming request parameters do not pass the given validation rules? As mentioned previously, Laravel will automatically redirect the user back to their previous location. In addition, all of the validation errors will automatically be flashed to the session.

Since you're not displaying the `$errors` variable, you're not getting any useful feedback. Try showing the value of `$errors->all()` in your form.

Comment: Side note: Setting a maximum password length is bad for security, and completely unnecessary when you're doing password hashing. Please consider ditching that max:16 rule.

Comment: Noted. Thank you for this!